# Avoiding variable-length stack arrays at compiletime

Tags: c, visual-studio, memory, c-preprocessor, nmake

I've implemented a function that requires some temporary stack space, the amount of which depends on one of its inputs. That smells like variable-length stack memory allocation, which is not always considered a good idea (e.g., it's not part of C90 or C++, and, in that context, only available in gcc through an extension). However, my situation is slightly different: I do know how many bytes I'll end up allocating at compile-time, it's just that it's different for several different calls to this function, sprinkled around my codebase.

C99 seems to be fine with this, but that's not what e.g. Visual Studio implements, and thus my CI runs on Windows are failing.

It seems that I have a few options, none of which are great. I hope this question can either convince me of one of these, or provide a more idiomatic alternative.

- Allocate the stack space outside of the function call, based on the compile-time constant that I'd otherwise pass as a parameter, and then pass a pointer.
- Turn my function into a macro.
- Turn my function into a wrapper-macro that then allocates the stack space and passes it on to the 'real' function (essentially combining 1 and 2).
- Somehow convince Visual Studio that this is fine ([relevant NMakefile](https://github.com/PQClean/PQClean/blob/d791a849113084c2f4fd3fb222a8abd0cbc93f08/crypto_sign/sphincs-shake256-128f-simple/clean/Makefile.Microsoft_nmake)).

The goal here is not only to get something that *works* and is reasonably performant but also that *is readable and clean*, as that strongly aligns with the context of the project this is part of. I should note that allocation on the heap is also not an option here.

How can I best deal with this?

If you prefer more hands-on, real-world context, [here's a Github comment where I describe my specific instance of this problem](https://github.com/PQClean/PQClean/pull/90#issuecomment-480499953).

Comment: *That smells like dynamic stack memory allocation, which is a Bad Idea.*  Oh?  Why is that a "Bad Idea"?  Why does the stack exist then?

Comment: I’m assuming dynamic memory allocation is out of the question?  If so, your first option would make the most sense.

Comment: @AndrewHenle There are endless discussions about this that are beside the point of this question; e.g., it's standard C99, but not part of C++11, although many compilers do support it as an extension. I'll reformulate to avoid controversy.

Comment: @JohnBode Ah, yes, that's relevant context. Thanks!

Comment: @Joost Thank you.  Way too many questions get posted based on cargo-cult programming ideas, and your use of "Bad Idea" seemed to fall into that.

Comment: Perhaps the MSVC is the **bad** thing here.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I agree - although here the setting is slightly different, as I simply took the 'bad idea'-opinion as a given (evidenced by VS' lack of support, regardless of whether I agree/disagree in general), and precisely focus on how to get away with it anyway in a specific context where I argue it's not at all bad (i.e., everything is known compile-time).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Sadly, one cannot change the wind -- only adjust the sails.

Comment: @Joost sure one can... just choose another direction :D

Comment: Depending on the size of the required allocation, you could test for `_MSC_VER` and use `_malloca()` if you needed to. I think the size limit is 1K or thereabouts.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Ah, interesting! Thanks! Unfortunately, the (infrequent) maximum is typically ~2KiB, which is why I was reluctant to fix it to that (given that the usual case is ~128 bytes).

Comment: @Joost: Well, the better solution would have been `_alloca()`, but that function is deprecated. The `_malloca()` function will attempt heap allocation if the requested size is too large, so that's a no-go.

Comment: @Joost: I've never tested it, so I'm not sure, but you could try redefining the `_ALLOCA_S_THRESHOLD` value to something larger than 1024 and test it to see.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently MSVC does handle C99 compound literals (§6.5.2.5), so you can pass stack-allocated arrays directly to the called function as additional arguments. You might want to use a macro to simplify the call syntax.

Here's an example:

```
/* Function which needs two temporary arrays. Both arrays and the size
 * are passed as arguments
 */
int process(const char* data, size_t n_elems, char* stack, int* height) {
  /* do the work */
}

/* To call the function with n_elems known at compile-time */
int result = process(data, N, (char[N]){0}, (int[N]){0});

/* Or you might use a macro like this: */
#define process_FIXED(D, N) (process(D, N, (char[N]){0}, (int[N]){0})))
int result = process_FIXED(data, N);
```

The `process` function doesn't need to know how the temporaries are allocated; the caller could just as well `malloc` the arrays (and free them after the call) or use a VLA or `alloca` to stack-allocate them.

Compound literals are initialised. But they cannot be too large, because otherwise you risk stack overflow, so the overhead shouldn't be excessive. But that's your call. Note that in C, an initialiser list cannot be empty although GCC seems to accept `(char[N]){}` without complaint. MSVC complains, or at least the on-line compiler I found for it complains.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to offer both:

**module.h**

```
// Helper macro for calculating correct buffer size
#define CALC_SIZE(quantity)  (/* expands to integer constant expression */)

// C90 compatible function
void func(uint8_t * data, int quantity);

// Optional function for newer compilers
// uses CALC_SIZE internally for simpler API similarly to 'userFunc' below
#if NOT_ANCIENT_COMPILER
void funcVLA(int quantity);
#endif
```

**user.c**

```
#include "module.h"
void userFunc(void) {
    uint8_t buffer[CALC_SIZE(MY_QUANTITY)];
    func(buffer, MY_QUANTITY);
}
```